# Computationally efficiently convert dtypes of multiple DataFrame columns to one single dtype all at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, multiple-columns

the function is the following:

```
def func1(df):
    df = df.loc[:,['code',
                  'currentPrice',
                  'hedgingValue',
                  'exercisePrice',
                  'outstanding(%)',
                  'expiryDate'
                  ]].dropna()

    df['code'] = df['code'].str[:5]
    df['currentPrice'] = df['currentPrice'].astype(float)
    df['hedgingValue'] = df['hedgingValue'].astype(float)
    df['exercisePrice'] = (df['exercisePrice'].str.replace(',','')).astype(int)
    df['outstanding(%)'] = (df['outstanding(%)'].str[:-1]).astype(float)
    df['expiryDate'] = df['expiryDate'].astype(int)

    return df
```

two lines that convert df['currentPrice'] and df['hedgingValue'] from string into float are so ineffective in that what if there are 100 columns instead of two? So there's gotta be a way to convert multiple columns(let's say there are 100) into float using only a one line code. My question is what is that magic one line code that does the trick? Thank you guys in advance.

Note that df.apply() is notoriously slow and inefficient at handling a large DataFrame, so it is definitely not the answer for this situation.

Comment: What makes the current function ineffective? How long does it take on your current dataset, and do you realistically expect ever to have 100 columns of numbers as strings that you need to convert?

Comment: @Peter Leimbigler Realistically, I expect about 5-10 columns of numbers(probably tens of thousands of rows) as strings that I need to convert to float. As for the performance, it is not like right now it is slow; it is more like I want it to be even faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to perform multiple conversion in one line. This can be done with

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', ...]
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float)
```

Comment: Thank you RafaelC. This's what I am looking for. Have a good day.